# Handler.postDelayed running for extra time

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

I am writing an handler to run for an fix amount(30 Sec) time. Basic on that it update counter to draw a view component.

```
counterRunnable = new Runnable() {
            int currV = 0;

            public void run(){

                if(count >= 360) {
                    counterHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    onTimerComplete();
                } else {
                    count++;
                    counterHandler.postDelayed(this, 83); // (30/360) = ~83
                }
            }
        };
```

As I am running back it for delay of **83ms for 360 time (83*360 = 29880ms  ~30 Sec)** but it is running for **~39 sec**. Any suggestion if I am doing anything wrong.

**Analysis:**
I checked same with [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))(scheduled at fix rate) and it's performing better as compare [Handler.postDelay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) but still any suggestion **why postDelay worst here** ?

Comment: Why dont you just use timer which is usually the proper solutionf or your purpose?

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold I am checking with that..but what is wrong if I just execute mention code.any suggestion here ?

Comment: How often does the view need to be updated? Why not just use 1000ms for your `postDelayed` call and count to 30?

Comment: Testing this snippet and nothing else gives a delay of 29970ms. Is this Runnable running on the main thread, or on some other thread under considerable load?

Comment: @Squonk I need some smooth draw..so require with this little delay.

Comment: @PokasOaskas It;s on main thread.

Comment: It might be better for you to put this Runnable on a separate thread, and run your updating code using runOnUiThread().

Comment: @Shubh : What sort of view are you drawing?

Comment: @PokasOaskas yes that I should try..thanks.

Comment: @Squonk I am drawing an circular progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5825063/1668144) answer and implement this behaviour with AlarmManager.

As you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)), there can be an additional delay for the runnable to start running. Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5824951/1668144) explanation from @CommonsWare:

> Android is not a real-time operating system. All postDelayed()
>   guarantees is that it will be at least the number of milliseconds
>   specified. Beyond that will be dependent primarily on what the main
>   application thread is doing (if you are tying it up, it cannot process
>   the Runnable), and secondarily on what else is going on the device
>   (services run with background priority and therefore get less CPU time
>   than does the foreground).

**Edit:** Keep in mind that `Timer` creates a new thread for your code to be executed. So it doesn't depend on main thread's workload. You can check a discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813241/1668144)

Comment: postDelayed(..), got it but then how Timer is working in same case. Regards AlarmManager, will not be usable since I have very little delay to process.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think that the difference is basically because the handler is executing this runnable in the main thread and the timer creates a new thread.

Comment: Does this answer helped you? If so, can you mark it as good? otherwise can you write your own solution?

Comment: Yes it make sense but this is not final solution ..Timer I tried could be alternative here. I am checking with HandlerThread, if it could be best way to use Handler in separate thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html